# Something wrong with character input and switch case in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement, character, scanf

There is a question in which it takes the no: of cases and in each case it takes no: of objects and each object is either a point or circle or line segment. I have written complete code but the switch case is not working. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int test,nob,ans[4],px,py,cx,cy,cr,lx1,ly1,lx2,ly2,flag,i,j;
    char type;

    scanf("%d",&test); //no:of test cases

    while(test) {

        flag=0;
        scanf("%d",&nob); //no:of objects
        while(nob)
        {
            scanf("%c\\n",&type); //what type of object
            switch(type)
            {
            case 'p':
                {
                    scanf("%d%d",&px,&py);
                    if((px<=ans[0] && py<=ans[1] && px>=ans[2] && py>=ans[3])|| flag==0) {
                        ans[0]=px;ans[1]=py;ans[2]=px;ans[3]=py;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case 'c':
                {
                    scanf("%d%d%d",&cx,&cy,&cr);
                    if((cx-cr<=ans[0] && cy-cr<=ans[1] && cx+cr>=ans[2] && cy+cr>=ans[3])|| flag==0) {
                        ans[0]=cx-cr;ans[1]=cy-cr;ans[2]=cx+cr;ans[3]=cy+cr;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case 'l':
                {
                    scanf("%d%d%d%d",&lx1,&ly1,&lx2,&ly2);
                    if((lx1<=ans[0] && ly1<=ans[1] && lx2>=ans[2] && ly2>=ans[3])|| flag==0) {
                        ans[0]=lx1;ans[1]=ly1;ans[2]=lx2;ans[3]=ly2;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            default:
                printf("you entered wrong letter.");
            }
            flag=1;
            nob--;
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            printf("%d ",ans[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        test--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When you run this program, the `switch case` is not working. I think so there is something wrong in taking the input of type character. pls help me. I have been trying to solve this bug for 3 days.

Comment: An answer explains the fault, but also should `flag` and `nob` not be set when a bad entry caused the `default` case?

Comment: @Weather vane ,I am sorry ..I didn't understand what u have asked.

Comment: I was saying, after the `switch` statement you modify `flag` and `nob`. But if there was an invalid input, causing the `default:` case, did you still want those two variable updates? If not, move them to each of the other individual (successful) `case` statements. See the answer's update.

Comment: Yeah,I didn't recognize it.The answer's update is correct .I will change it .Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has to be a space before `%c` - also the `\\n` is not needed here:

```
scanf(" %c", &type); //what type of object
```

Otherwise, the `newline` (`\n`) from the previous `scanf()` will be read in as `type` (this is not needed for `%d`).

You also need to define `ans`:

```
int ans[4] = {0};
```

And `j` is not used - can be removed:

```
'j' : unreferenced local variable
```

Also, as [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) mentioned, in case of bad input for `type`, `flag` and `nob` should not be updated. You can fix this as follows:

```
default :
    printf("you entered wrong letter.");
    continue;
}
flag=1;
nob--;
```

Comment: Thats very much helped and corrected my code completely.can u pls explain why should we keep space before %c .

Comment: The space before `%c` consumes all leading whitespace in the input buffer. In your case, it was the `newline` left over after a `%d` entry. It is not needed for `%d` or `%s` or other types, which automactically consume leading whitespace. I hate `scanf`.

Comment: @harry - For the previous `scanf()` for `nob`, you had to press enter to end the scan. The problem is that the newline that was entered is still in the buffer, and the next `scanf()` that scans for a single char will read in the enter first. So `type` wil have the value '\n'.

Comment: Thank u so much for that.Its very informative and accurate.U really deserve credit and i have given it.Bye